# bash expect stops after ***

Tags: bash, expect

I have a very simple expect script to connect to a Cisco Wireless Lan Controller via Cisco router.
My problem is that after some commands expect stops suddenly without finish all sentences and without any error.
I think that the problem is with * from password but I'm not sure.
That's my script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10

spawn telnet X.Y.Z.W

expect "User Access Verification"
expect "Username:"
send "admin\r"
expect "Password:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "Router#"
send "telnet WLC_IP\r"
expect "(Cisco Controller)"
expect "User:"
send "admin\r"
expect "Password:"
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "Cisco Controller"
send " config paging disable\r"
expect "Cisco Controller"
send " show ap auto-rf 802.11b AP-NAME\r"
expect "Cisco Controller"
send "logout\r";
```

And this is the output after running,

```
spawn telnet X.Y.Z.W
Trying X.Y.Z.W...
Connected to X.Y.Z.W.
Escape character is '^]'.


User Access Verification

Username: admin
Password:

Router#telnet WLC_IP
Trying WLC_IP ... Open

(Cisco Controller)
User: admin
Password:**********
(Cisco Controller) >?

clear          Clear selected configuration elements.
config         Configure switch options and settings.
cping          Send capwap echo packets to a specified mobility peer IP address.
debug          Manages system debug options.
eping          Send Ethernet-over-IP echo packets to a specified mobility peer IP address.
grep           Print lines matching a pattern.
help           Help
license        Manage Software License
linktest       Perform a link test to a specified MAC address.
logout         Exit this session. Any unsaved changes are lost.
mping          Send Mobility echo packets to a specified mobility peer IP address.
ping           Send ICMP echo packets to a specified IP address.
reset          Reset options.
save           Save switch configurations.
show           Display switch options and settings.
test           Test trigger commands
transfer       Transfer a file to or from the switch.

(Cisco Controller) >config paging disable


(Cisco Controller) >[root@mailman scripts]#
```

Also, there are an "?" after password that I don't know why is it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need the space at the beginning of `send " config paging disable\r"`? I think that may be triggering command completion.

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to http://superuser.com/

Comment: The space is not necessary, was only a test, I have the same behavior with space or without it.

Comment: I have checked again without space and expect still stopts but "?" dissapear.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` before the spawn command. Examine the (verbose) debug output. Are there any errors there?

Answer (score 0):

after setting `expect eof` at the end of my script it works well! I'm not sure if it's mandatory but works for me.

Thank you!